# Android Intents : Receive text data without showing the receiving activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-sharing

I've noticed when trying to share text from other Apps and choosing Facebook to save, Facebook's Receiving Activity doesn't open (At least it's that fast, maybe), it only shows a toast confirmation message.

**This is how I tried doing it**

```
private void welcomeSharedData(){
        Intent intent       = getIntent();
        String action       = intent.getAction();
        String type         = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent);
                saveTextAsNote();
                toastMessage();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

My problem with the above is, my App shows a flashing screen of the Activity then goes back to the Calling App.

**I want it to be quiet and only reply with a confirmation message on a toast.**

Comment: what theme is your app/activity using?

Comment: @pskink its "AppTheme_NoActionBar"

Comment: tried `@android:style/Theme.Translucent` or similar?

Comment: @pskink you should have put that as an Answer so I can accept it. After google per your reference I found out that I should create a Translucent Theme and set it only for that activity when the activity is invoked from shared.